# proper way to specify optional dependencies of a gem in ruby Gemfile

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

a gem intends to support gems `a` or `b` as alternatives for a functionality.

In code I check with `defined?(A)` if I fall back to `b` that's fine.

But as a gem developer how to specify these dependencies?

1) what do I put in the Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'a', :require => false
  gem 'b', :require => false
end
```

This allows `Bundle.require(:test)` not to auto-require a,b?

2) How can explicitly require `a` and `b` separately to mimic (or mock) the scenario when we fall back to `b` in my tests?

3) Also how do I specify that either `a` or `b` is prerequisite for the gem.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Don't include the `a` gem in your dependencies, but `require` it anyway. If that fails, it will raise `LoadError`, from which you can rescue.

```
begin
  require 'a'
rescue LoadError
  # The 'a' gem is not installed
  require 'b'
end
```

---

I believe this is the best way to use and test this setup:

1. Define an interface for your backend and allow a custom implementation to be easily plugged in.

   ```
   module YourGem
     class << self
       attr_accessor :backend

       def do_something_awesome
         backend.do_something_awesome
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Implement the `a` and `b` backends.

   ```
   # your_gem/backends/a.rb
   require 'a'

   module YourGem::Backends::A
     def self.do_something_awesome
       # Do it
     end
   end

   # your_gem/backends/b.rb
   require 'b'

   module YourGem::Backends::B
     def self.do_something_awesome
       # Do it
     end
   end
   ```
3. Set the one you want to use.

   ```
   begin
     require 'your_gem/backends/a'
     Gem.backend = YourGem::Backends::A
   rescue LoadError
     require 'your_gem/backends/b'
     Gem.backend = YourGem::Backends::B
   end
   ```

   This will use `YourGem::Backend::A` even if `b` is installed.
4. Before testing, make sure both `a` and `b` gems are installed, `require` both backends in the test code, run the tests with one backend, then run the tests again with the other backend.

Comment: this is ok for implementation code, but in tests what is best practice to mock require to throw this LoadError?

Comment: @viktortron, I've updated my answer. This is a rather unusual setup, but that's how I'd test it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same question a while ago. My solution was to think that the developer should specify this behavior. I would not specify it on the gem, but on the wiki. I would recommend you to document it clearly that the developer need to define one of the dependencies.

To make it better, you can make a check on initialization of the gem, looking for the dependencies, if none can be found, just raise a runtime exception or if you prefer, your own exception. =)

Comment: thx, you have a view on 3) then, maybe 1): you do not mention these gems correct? any thoughts on 2)?

Comment: I didnt understand your comment. =/